# Usar clases como atributos de otras clases en typescript

Tags: nodejs, typescript, funciones, diseño-de-clases, atributos

Hola tengo tres clases: Coche, motor y rueda y estas dos últimas a su vez son atributos de la clase coche. El código es el siguiente:

```
class Rueda {
marca: string;
modelo: string;
medida: number;
constructor(a: string, b: string, c:number) {
this.marca= a;
this.modelo= b;
this.medida= c; 
}
}

class Motor {
marca: string;
modelo: string;
año: number;
tipocombustible: string;
constructor(m:string, mod:string, a:number, c: string){
this.marca = m;
this.modelo = mod;
this.año = a; 
this.tipocombustible = c
}
}

class Coche {
marca: string;
modelo: string;
ruedas:Rueda[];
motores:Motor[]
constructor(a: string, b: string, d: Rueda[], c:Motor[]) {
this.marca= a;
this.modelo= b;
this.ruedas=d;
this.motores=c;
}
}
```

ahora cuando declaro coche1 no me reconoce lo que hay dentro de los arrays que corresponde con las clases Rueda y Motor, exactamente lo que dice es "el tipo string no se puede asignar con el tipo Rueda"

```
let coche1= new Coche('Audi', 'A4', ['Michelin', 'Pilot', '17'],['Mercedes','s30', 1995,'diesel'])
```

No encuentro el fallo y necesito ayuda.

Muchas gracias.

PD: Esas 3 clases se encuentran en módulos distintos, los atributos son privatos y todas ellas tienen métodos set y get. Tengo que declarar coche 1 en un archivo vehículos.ts. ¿En este caso tendría que instanciar un nuevo motor y una nueva rueda no?. Si es así, ¿cómo sería?

Además rueda y motor son utilizadas luego en una función para cambiarlas

Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: No uses clases como tipos, en vez de eso, usa interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

De la forma en que estas haciendo una el `motor` y la `rueda` son una `clase`, por lo que tendrías que instanciar un nuevo `motor` y una nueva `rueda` para pasársela por parámetro a `coche`

```
class Rueda {
    marca: string;
    modelo: string;
    medida: number;
    constructor(a: string, b: string, c: number) {
        this.marca = a;
        this.modelo = b;
        this.medida = c;
    }
}

class Motor {
    marca: string;
    modelo: string;
    año: number;
    tipocombustible: string;
    constructor(m: string, mod: string, a: number, c: string) {
        this.marca = m;
        this.modelo = mod;
        this.año = a;
        this.tipocombustible = c
    }
}

class Coche {
    marca: string;
    modelo: string;
    ruedas: Rueda[];
    motores: Motor[]
    constructor(a: string, b: string, d: Rueda[], c: Motor[]) {
        this.marca = a;
        this.modelo = b;
        this.ruedas = d;
        this.motores = c;
    }
}

let rueda1 = new Rueda('Michelin', 'Pilot', 17)

let motor1 = new Motor('Mercedes','s30', 1995, 'diesel')

let coche1= new Coche('Audi', 'A4', [rueda1], [motor1])
```

Pero una forma mejor si tu `motor` y `rueda` no van a tener métodos propios lo mejor es usar una interfaz, para no andar creando clases innecesarias, que luego se transforma en código innecesario cuando compilas a JavaScript.

```
interface Rueda {
    marca: string;
    modelo: string;
    medida: number;
}

interface Motor {
    marca: string;
    modelo: string;
    año: number;
    tipocombustible: string;
}

class Coche {
    marca: string;
    modelo: string;
    ruedas: Rueda[];
    motores: Motor[]
    constructor(a: string, b: string, d: Rueda[], c: Motor[]) {
        this.marca = a;
        this.modelo = b;
        this.ruedas = d;
        this.motores = c;
    }
}


let rueda1 = {marca: 'Michelin', modelo: 'Pilot', medida: 17}

let motor1 = {marca: 'Mercedes', modelo: 's30', año: 1995, tipocombustible: 'diesel'}

let coche1 = new Coche('Audi', 'A4', [rueda1], [motor1])
```